# Extracting BitsPerSample from a RIFF WAV File

Tags: c#, hex, wav, filereader

I'm trying to extract the BitsPerSample from a WAV file using FileStream. According to this source: [WAV offset Table](http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html), the BitsPerSample is located at offset 35 and is 2 bytes long.

This is my code for trying to extract it:

```
public int getBitsPerSample()
{
    int bitsPerSample;
    using (var f = File.OpenRead(wavPath))
    {
        f.Seek(35,SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] val = new byte[2];
        f.Read(val,0,2);
        bitsPerSample = BitConverter.ToInt16(val,0);
    }
    return bitsPerSample;
}
```

Now when I use this on a WAV file i know is 16 bit, i get a bitsPerSample of 25600? When i used a hex editor to view te WAV file my suspicions were comfirmed, the 2 bytes were actually at offset 0x22, right before it says "d a t a", where it should be. Inspecting a different 16bit WAV file confirmed this.

Seeking at 0x22 gave me bitspersample of 2, which is also not correct.

If someone already knows the problem by now thats great, but im gonna keep adding some info in case it's needed.

When I opened a 32 bit WAV file in a hex editor I found the bitsPerSample at offset 0x4E, which is again completely different from my source, and my last result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are misinterpreting the offsets from the linked resource. They are 1-based. The file seeking works obviously 0-based. So seek to byte 34 instead and try again.